# JS Scroll Top Error on wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I used following code to scroll page to some point.

```
<a type="scroll" id="scroll" class="btn btn-info hochschulbtn" role="button" onclick="jQuery('.mainTabPanel .osc-res-nav').find('li:eq(4) a').tab('show');jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#tabTitle_pro').offset().top-110}, 2000);" href="javascript:;">Young Professionals/ Berufseinsteiger</a>
```

But It works only when I'm logged in. When I'm not logged in it doesn't work. 
You can check : https://www.inwerken.de/youngprofessionals/

Comment: `jQuery("#scroll").on('click', function() { jQuery('.mainTabPanel .osc-res-nav').find('li:eq(4) a').tab('show');jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#tabTitle_pro').offset().top-110}, 2000); });` May I know why you call jquery click in onclick

Comment: Works for me event if i'm not logged in

Comment: Did it scroll up ? When logged off it went down but it should be scroll up.